# Разрушенное здание можно ли назвать каменоломней?

Tags: выбор-слов

Войны, пожары, землятресение *(одно?)*, эпидемии, голод – бесконечные бедствия обратили центр цивилизации в жалкое зрелище. Многие **в прошлом прекрасные здания были обращены в каменоломни**. Площади были полны просителями – обнищавшими крестьянами и римской чернью, среди которых нередко укрывались разбойники, терроризирующие не только город, но и подступы к нему.

А "центр цивилизации, обращённый в жалкое зрелище" - сойдёт?

Ну, первое "обратили" я поправлю на "превратили", а в общем и целом - как жить?

Comment: _...в каменный лом..._

Comment: "Нескончаемые" лучше с бедствиями сочетается. Полны **просителей** (просителями же - наполнены или полнились). Терроризировали "жителей подступов"?

Comment: @slava1947, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каменоломня - место где производится добыча камня для использования в строительстве. Если камни "добывали" из старых зданий, то такое можно назвать каменоломней.

"Обратили в жалкое зрелище" мне кажется неприемлемым. В Нацкорпусе по ключу  "жалкий" и "зрелище* находим только "представлять/являть собой"

"Просители" в каком смысле? Попрошайки? Корректно ли это?

ПРОСИТЕЛЬ, -я; м. 1. Устар. Тот, кто обращается с прошением к кому-л. или куда-л. Приём просителей. Отказать просителям. Толпа просителей в приёмной. 2. Тот, кто обращается с просьбой к кому-л. Выступать в роли просителя. Никто не любит быть просителем.

Может, стоит выделить вставную конструкцию двумя тире:

Площади были полны просителями (попрошайками?) — обнищавшими крестьянами и римской чернью(,) — среди которых нередко укрывались разбойники, терроризирующие не только город, но и подступы к нему.

Comment: М_Г! Беру попрошаек и представлять/являть собой, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Слово уже употреблялось в таком значении:

Но культура ― творение рук и ума людей ― стала жертвой статистического процесса энтропии, осуществляемого руками людей (античные постройки, **превращённые в каменоломни**). [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по истории искусства (1999)]